# axios get request returning the vue index.html file for all static html files i'm trying to serve

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, axios

So, I have a vue app that's working well on my MAC running `npm run serve`.

Running `npm run build` and deploy my code to my CENTOS environment (using NGINX) all of the .get requests are coming back are returning a 200 in the network tab, but the content should be a static html file that i'm pulling into my app.

here are some code samples:

```
this.axios.get(flatHtmlLocation).then(response => {
                let corsHTML = response.data;
                let htmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(corsHTML, "text/html");
                this.rawDog = htmlDoc;
                this.htmlData = htmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
            })
```

^ this works just fine when I'm playing around on my Mac.

I'm pulling my static .html files from the /public/ directory in a specific directory.

Here is what my file structure looks like:

name of app

```
-- public
     index.html
     /directory-where-static-html-lives/filename.html 
  -- src
     -- components/component/file_pulling_the_static_asset.vue
```

Here is a copy of my .conf (NGINX) file for the app in prod that I'm using:

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    server_name _;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://some-fancy-pants-url:4000;
    }
 location /public/ {
        root /opt/location-of-my-app;
    }

    location / {
        root    /opt/location-of-my-app/dist;
        index    index.html index.htm;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }



}
```

[image: 200 response from axios GET on production after npm run build]

[image: content of 200 response is the static Vue.js html landing page]

[image: VUE /public/ html landing page..]

Comment: The problem here seems to be with your nginx configuration, not the code per se. This question might be answered better on ServerFault rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing too.. but i'm unsure how to configure my .conf file to serve the static files properly.. I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: Try asking posting your question on serverfault.com. In case you aren't aware of it, that's the sister site of stack overflow but geared towards system administration and configuration and such, so the people over there can probably help you better.